# Select just one element with multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fire an onClick function on a button that toggles an input with class "changes" which is **not** in the same div as the button. I have various input elements with the same classes that are created dynamically. I need to target just one input element. These inputs are not in the same div as the button I want to click:

This was my previous approach:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container flex-row">
<textarea class="changes-input flex-item-16 form-control" placeholder="text" type="text"></textarea>
<div class="flex-item flex-self-no-padding" style="min-width: 65px">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
        <button id="edit-change-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="rejectChange(2)">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#the-button').click(function () {
    input = $(this).parent("div").find('.changes-input');
    $(input).removeClass("changes-text-area-selected");
    $(input).toggleClass("changes-textarea-normal");
});
```

Comment: I do not see `id="the-button"` in your markup

Comment: There is not enough information to determine what hooks you can use to uniquely identify the particular `input` you are looking for. Does it have a unique set of class names (or other attributes)? Does it have a unique relationship to the button being clicked, or to some other uniquely identifiable element? These are the questions to ask yourself, and then the task will be to create a selector that accords with those answers.

Comment: Absolutely there must a different selection attribute in the target div for to pick correct. If you have many div's and they have no any different points, then you can pick any one by using their indexes; for example **$("div").eq(0)**  will select the first div!

Comment: Taplar I apologize, the-button class was an example for this thread. the actual id is "edit-change-btn" which I do have in the markup. I'll edit the question to change it, sorry. Kevin, all attributes are the same for each element generated. I was able to achieve what I wanted by targeting the class .changes-input and using onClick and this. It selects only the current element I clicked with .changes-input class. But it does't work when I try it on a div outside div.flex-item.flex-self-no-padding